# Clustering problems with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, clustering

*I originally posted the question on SO but just realised it was more suited here... I am copying the question below, not sure what the rule is, just let me know if I need to remove the other one from SO.*

I am using the JMS clustering community plugin of GeoServer. I want to build a cluster of map servers mainly with horizontal scaling.

I have generated an image and run my geoserver with the JMS extensions in a container. At the moment I am only testing with a docker-compose but my goal is to use it in a Kubernetes cluster.

It took me a day more or less to have it "kind" of working in a multi master/slave configuration. In fact all nodes are both master and slaves.

The issues I have are the following:

- Partial duplication of data. Data does get copied from one node to another but not always. The workspaces in particular seem to have more issues (?)
- if I boot a new node then it starts blank, none of the initialisation is done. I would expect a new node to have all its data initialised by another node?
- if I use the web interface, every time I log in one node it logs me out the other nodes!
- occasionally if I create an element (more often a workspace) it complains it was already created, as if the message bounced back to the server.

Here's a template cluster file properties for the nodes:

```
CLUSTER_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/geoserver/data_dir/cluster
instanceName=$INSTANCENAME
readOnly=disabled
durable=true
brokerURL=
embeddedBroker=enabled
connection.retry=10
toggleMaster=true
xbeanURL=./broker.xml
embeddedBrokerProperties=embedded-broker.properties
topicName=VirtualTopic.geoserver
connection=enabled
toggleSlave=true
connection.maxwait=500
group=geoserver-cluster
```

And the embedded-broker.properties

```
## JMX settings (can be overridden by env vars)
## For more information, see: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
# enable/disable broker jmx
activemq.jmx.useJmx=false
# set the JMX connector port
activemq.jmx.port=1098
# set the JMX connector host
activemq.jmx.host=$DOCKERIP
# enable the JMX connector
activemq.jmx.createConnector=false

## broker settings
# set the base path of the temporary broker dir
# this is also used as persistence base dir
#activemq.base=./

## configuring the embedded broker
# connects the server via native I/O socket to the local network broadcast using an automatic assigned port
# maximumConnections and wireFormat.maxFrameSize are added to avoid ddos attacks
activemq.transportConnectors.server.uri=tcp://$DOCKERIP:0?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&jms.useAsyncSend=true&transport.daemon=true&trace=true

## the broker performs discovery using the following protocol:
# multicast on default network
activemq.transportConnectors.server.discoveryURI=multicast://default

## persistence settings and system usage
## The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
## use before slowing down producers.
## For more information, see: http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
# enable/disable persistence
activemq.broker.persistent=true
# heap memory usage
activemq.broker.systemUsage.memoryUsage=128 mb
# disk space memory usage
activemq.broker.systemUsage.storeUsage=1 gb
# temp disk space memory usage
activemq.broker.systemUsage.tempUsage=128 mb
```

My docker compose (main elements)

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  geoserver:
      image: geocento/geoserver
      ports:
        - "8650:8080"
      restart: on-failure
      env_file:
        - geoserver.env
      networks:
        geoserver2:
  geoserver2:
      image: geocento/geoserver
      ports:
        - "8651:8080"
      restart: on-failure
      env_file:
        - geoserver.env
      networks:
        geoserver2:
etc...
networks:
  geoserver2:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.0.0/24
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any way out?

Comment: I kind of did make it work but it's long and windy :) I will try to create a helm chart and put it on GitHub. I'll post it as an answer when I have it working.

Comment: Actually I did it by myself ... I don't why but I had a problem with versions of geoserver and relating extension clustering. Finally I used `Geoserver 2.17.2` and `geoserver-2.16-SNAPSHOT-jms-cluster-plugin`. Now it works fine, faster then before.